# Validating Scanner to only allow characters

Tags: java

Here's my first question. I'm taking an online coding class, and it definitely has some holes in the instruction. We have been tasked with taking 2 different inputs that are one character only, and converting them to ASCII values. I have that down pat, I'm struggling with how I'm supposed to validate the inputs to only allow one character, and not something such as a number or symbol, and then exit the program if such an error arises. Here's my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class AndrewBrutonMod4TopSecret
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner kaReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first initial of your first name:");
        String i1 = kaReader.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the first initial of your last name:");
        String i2 = kaReader.next();
        char a = i1.charAt(0);
        char b = i2.charAt(0);
        char a1 = Character.toUpperCase(a);
        char b1 = Character.toUpperCase(b);
        int c = (int)a;
        int d = (int)b;
        System.out.println("Initials: "+a1+" "+b1);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Initials: "+c+" "+d);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm struggling with how I'm supposed to validate the inputs to only
>   allow one character, and not something such as a number or symbol

You can use isAlphabetic() method

Javadoc:

> Determines if the specified character (Unicode code point) is an
>   alphabet. A character is considered to be alphabetic if its general
>   category type, provided by getType(codePoint), is any of the
>   following:
>
> UPPERCASE_LETTER
>
> LOWERCASE_LETTER
>
> TITLECASE_LETTER
>
> MODIFIER_LETTER
>
> OTHER_LETTER
>
> LETTER_NUMBER
>
> or it has contributory
>   property Other_Alphabetic as defined by the Unicode Standard.

```
private static boolean isValidChar(char ch) {
    return Character.isAlphabetic(ch);
}
```

> and then exit the program if such an error arises

For example

```
if (!isValidChar(a))
    System.exit(-1);
```